# finding end of disjoint row VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count, cell

It is possible this question has already been asked and I didn't spot it in my research.

I have a row of numbers, which starts at "DC:4" on a spread sheet. This row can increase or decrease in length (possibly going up to "GG:4"). For a given run of my macro I wish to find the number of none empty cells in row 4, so it could be 2 or 262.
I could do something like:

```
     Sheets("sheet 1").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

But, this fails due to the 106 blanks cells before this row of numbers starts. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using WorksheetFunctions Count and CountA.

If you want the number of non-empty cells in row 4 use the `CountA`

`WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(4))`

If you want the number of cells that contain only numbers in row 4 use the `Count`

`WorksheetFunction.Count(Rows(4))`

Comment: @MrNemo Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Sheets("sheet 1").UsedRange.Specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column`

This usually returns the right column

If you want to check for a certain row, use it like this:

```
Sheets("sheet 1").Rows(4).Entirerow.Specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that is really helpful (and a useful bit of code), but for some reason when I use the later of the above I get the longest row on the sheet, not the specified row? Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's not working how i thought it would, haven't tried it out

Comment: still nice though mate